# Adding days to only date and then subtracting it from date in c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I know this topic has already been discussed but I want to add days to only date, not the complete datetime and then I need to subtract it with date. What I have done till now is :

```
string endDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToShortDateString();
```

Now this gives me string like `19-jan-17` which is great but when I want to subtract it with todays date, it gives error because the end date is in string. I tried below code:

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() - endDate ;
```

or

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() - Convert.ToDateTime(endDate)
```

or

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() - Convert.ToString(endDate)
```

and if I change `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` to `DateTime.Now` then it will also include time which I do not want. I just want to add days in date only and then subtract it with today's date.

Any suggestions. Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to compare datetimes and strings at all? Store the datetime not the string. _If_ you want to _display_ it use `ToString` or `ToShortDateString`, not before. If you want to ignore the time portion of a `DateTime` use `DateTime.Date`, for example: `if(DateTime.Today == otherDateTime.Date)...`

Comment: What is the expected output? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2);

TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Today - endDate
```

The [`Today`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today(v=vs.110).aspx) property will return only the date part (so time will be 00:00:00), but still in a DateTime struct, so you can get a TimeSpan from subtracting another DateTime from it.

Comment: Thanks. but DateTime.Today also includes time 12:00. But its okay because the value of time remains same.

Comment: Of course it does. The DateTime structure can't hold date only. this is why the `Date` property as well as the`Today` property returns a date with midnight as the time portion.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try doing the following?

```
string endDate = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(2);
```

Still, it is not clear why you have to do that. A bit of context would be great for proposing other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I join Federico, you need to use the Date property of the DateTime instance. It will return the 00:00:00 moment of the date.

One side note: 
Just keep all dates in DateTime (e.g. do not convert them into strings) before calculating the diff. 
e.g.:

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Date - endDate;
```

If you need the date part, you can use format strings after the calculation.
e.g.:

```
endDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd")
```